Using GraphQL via GitLab to discover the first commit of a file in a repository
I am using GraphQL to access the contents of a .repository hosted in GitLab. I need specific information about the files in a repository. Specifically when it was last modified and when it was created.
Using GraphQL to get the last commit information about a file is fairly straight forward:

query($projectPath: ID!, $filePath :String){
 project(Path: $projectPath) {
>  repository {
>   tree(path: $filePath) {
>    lastCommit {
>     author {
>      name
>     }
>     committerEmail
>     committedDate
>    }
>   }
>  }
 }
}
{"fullPath":"my/path", "filePath": "myfile.txt"}

What I need is the first commit of a file, so that I can return the creation date of the file. So far, the Graphql schema in GitLab doesn't seem to cover this.
Any suggestions would be most welcome.
